# How do I convert my code into Lists Comprehension?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have the simple code , I just want to convert it into Lists Comprehensions , How can we do it ?

```
data=['Resaurants', 'Vibes', 'Drinks',18]
Invalid_Data=[]
Valid_Data=[]
for i in data:
    if i not in new_dict:
        Invalid_Data.append(i)
    if i in list(new_dict.keys()):
        Valid_Data.append(i)
```

Comment: `in list(new_dict.keys())` is a terrible way of checking if something is a key in your dictionary. Should just be `in new_dict`.

Comment: Edited , You can send me now by convert it into lists comprehensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in list(new_dict.keys())` is a terrible way of checking if something is a key in your dictionary, because every turn you're constructing an unnecessary list, and then checking if it contains the key is slower than just checking if the key is in the dictionary. Should just be `in new_dict`.

So list comprehensions:

```
invalid_data = [x for x in data if x not in new_dict]
valid_data = [x for x in data if x in new_dict]
```